# How to create a web based company dashboard that can be updated daily

Tags: html, report, dashboard

I am currently interning at an energy company. Everyday, a member of the staff here compiles a daily report that looks similar to a dashboard which contains everything the other members of the staff may need for the day from prices to performance of energy plants to different orders. He compiles this into an email and sends it out every morning to everyone else on staff.

He has tasked me with creating some sort of web portal or webpage dashboard that he can update every morning by simply plugging in the information on to the webpage every morning and then having the rest of the staff visit the site. This page can even be localized to our server alone.

How would I go about doing this in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

you should try it for dynamic web page, you used to jquery, ajax and websocket

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you should have some basic knowledge on HTML and some server side scripting language like php and you can start your application.

```
 1. Just create a MS-EXCEL file format for your report. 
 2. Write some html and php file to upload that file and process that file to a database.
 3. From there retrieve the data then you can show that in the dashboard.

http://blog.fossasia.org/import-excel-file-data-in-mysql-database-using-php/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKOz5fZ8HV0 
Credits: 
Prof Dr SabriErdem https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOb1774oAsUMAEBIrGHWqAg
```